# Powershell export output variable to file not found

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have the following script and as much as I try to send the output result, it does not go to the file and therefore the txt file is empty, if you can tell me where I am failing I would appreciate it.

```
Clear-Content .\telnet.txt

Write-host "Prueba de conexión de puertos"
'-'*30
' '*25 
$test = @('WEB:google.com:443','WEBSERVER_HTTP:www.noticias3d.com:80') 
Foreach ($t in $test)
{
  $description = $t.Split(':')[0]
  $source = $t.Split(':')[1]
  $port = $t.Split(':')[2]
  
  Write-Host "Conectando a $description host $source puerto $port"
  try
  {
    $socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($source, $port)
    $_.Message
  }
  catch [Exception]
  {
    Write-Host $_.Exception.GetType().FullName
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
  }


Out-File -FilePath telnet.txt

 Write-Host "Revisado`n"
}


#$wsh = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell

#$wsh.Popup("Finalizado checklist de Plataforma")
```

Comment: Write-Output instead  Write-Host it was the solution for capture the output. then i cant output to file

Answer (score 0):

As per the `out-file` help:

`The Out-File cmdlet sends output to a file`

In your example you haven't provided any output so you are just getting an empty file. Try

`"my file content" | Out-File -FilePath telnet.txt`

or just use the redirection operator:

`"my file content" > telnet.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving anything to `Out-File` to send. A foreach(...) statement does not produce pipeline output. Even if it did, you aren't actually chaining them together. Assign the output of the foreach loop to a variable, then pipe that variable to `Out-File`. I'd actually recommend you use `Set-Content` instead.

```
Clear-Content .\telnet.txt

Write-host "Prueba de conexión de puertos"
'-'*30
' '*25 
$test = @('WEB:google.com:443','WEBSERVER_HTTP:www.noticias3d.com:80') 
$result = Foreach ($t in $test)
{
  $description = $t.Split(':')[0]
  $source = $t.Split(':')[1]
  $port = $t.Split(':')[2]
  
  Write-Host "Conectando a $description host $source puerto $port"
  try
  {
    $socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($source, $port)
    $_.Message
  }
  catch [Exception]
  {
    Write-Host $_.Exception.GetType().FullName
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
  }


$result | Set-Content -FilePath telnet.txt

 Write-Host "Revisado`n"
}
```

As an alternative you could use the pipeline instead.

```
Clear-Content .\telnet.txt

Write-host "Prueba de conexión de puertos"
'-'*30
' '*25 
$test = @('WEB:google.com:443','WEBSERVER_HTTP:www.noticias3d.com:80') 
$test | ForEach-Object {

    $description = $_.Split(':')[0]
    $source = $_.Split(':')[1]
    $port = $_.Split(':')[2]
  
    Write-Host "Conectando a $description host $source puerto $port"
    try
    {
        $socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($source, $port)
        $_.Message
    }
    catch [Exception]
    {
        Write-Host $_.Exception.GetType().FullName
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
    }

} | Set-Content -FilePath telnet.txt

Write-Host "Revisado`n"
```

You also reference automatic variable `$_` in the line `$_.Message` which is referencing nothing.